# Where does cups store its configuration?

Tags: configuration, backup, printing, cups

I want to do a backup of my cups configuration to transfer it to a new system. But where does cups actually store the printer settings? I've watched `/etc/cups/` but the only thing that happened when adding a new printer was that the PPD was added to `/etc/cups/ppd/`.

Edit: A remark, the configuration actually is in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` but it was written delayed after actually adding the printer in the web interface. That was originally the reason I couldn't find it. So make sure everything was written, before doing a backup.

Comment: What version of CUPS? An older RHEL5 system I have has all sorts of `*.conf*` files under `/etc/cups`, in addition to the PPD directory. (If in doubt, crank logging or `strace` the daemon to find out what it is doing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Debian Jessie, the whole configuration is in `/etc/cups`:

```
classes.conf       
interfaces       
raw.convs  
subscriptions.conf  
cups-browsed.conf  
ppd         
raw.types  
subscriptions.conf   
cupsd.conf  
printers.conf  
snmp.conf  
cups-files.conf  
ssl
```

Is your system "non-linux"?